# word counter 'forgetting' about already saved word

Tags: c, struct

The snippets below are from my program that gets words, then prints them with the number of occurences.

It works almost fine except for it "forgots" that particular entry has been saved before and does NOT increment counter associated with it.

```
typedef struct {
    char *word;
    int occ;
}
words;
words *data=NULL;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *word;
    words *temp;
    int c,i,num;
    words *ptr = NULL;

    num=0;

    while(1)
    {
        c=fgetc(infile);
        if(c==EOF) break;
        if(!isalpha(c)) continue;
        else ungetc(c,infile);
        word=getword(infile);

        if(findword(word))
        {

            if(!(temp=realloc(data,sizeof(words)*(num+1))))
            { /* error handling */ }
            else
                data=temp;



        }
        else
           free(word);
    }

    /* sort procedure here, irrelevant for the purpose of topic */
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        /*printf*/
    }

    return 0;

}
```

What's wrong with that code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is your logic of adding the words? You just compare them and move on.

Comment: Everything is wrong with your code, is it H.W? start with using global variable data, and then returning it from a function , what is the point?? then non-existent allocation of a data->word, you just allocated a pointer without allocating space for the string it self, etc..., it is very badly written code !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that your "findword" function isn't actually finding a word; it's just looking at one item in the list.  It needs to loop.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that not finding the word was the /only/ problem. :-/

Comment: @twalberg if it finds a word then `if` condition (in findword) is false so it goes foe `else` in `main` where that particular ptr->occ is incremented.

Comment: @Peter Kowalski: Yes, but even that isn't going to work correctly, because the ptr being used is the one local to main and that only gets set (or left alone) by the previous "while (1)" iteration.  Actually, the way the code behaves is making me wonder whether I've been misled by the naming (including "findword") and it's actually only trying to recognize words repeated in a row.  What are you trying to have it print out for input "two one two"?

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((strcmp(word, ptr->word)) == 0) {
  //Do something to store the count
} 
else {
  return ptr;
}
```